# What is the path to the global directory for binary files in MacOS?

Tags: macos, administrator, zsh

What is the path to the global directory (for example: `/usr/local/bin` etc.) for binary files in MacOS?

The problem is that I can run the command from another user. With this command I want to start the Caddy web-server: `su _www -c caddy`

I know where this file is located. The problem is that Caddy can only work with php soket if the Caddy process is running from the user `_www`. But if I switch to `_www` user (this is not a problem), I can not start the process, because the Caddy file is in the `PATH` of another user.

Of course I can send the file to another user to run, but this is too long and inconvenient process. I just need to start the process from the right user. In Ubuntu, such a problem is not surprising.

I get this error:

[image]

Comment: You're asking the wrong question.  The error message clearly indicates a permissions issue, rather than locating the executable file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. It was enough to put a binary file Caddy in the directory: `/usr/local/bin`

If the binary file is in the directory `/usr/local/bin`, Caddy available for reading for user `_www`